# How can I convert a content in div to accordion tabs only on mobile view?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a div and its content to be clickable accordion tabs on mobile view.
It's too wide on desktop, its responsive but covers too much area in mobile view.

So I basically want my guests to click to accordion and see this big area then close it if they want.

I'm using wordpress, how can I achieve this? thanks...

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need to provide a lot more info to get a helpful response.  Reproduceable code samples, your attempts at solving the problem, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using media queries
@media min-width & max-width

Specify the style you want to the mobile view at min-width

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    /* styles goes here */
}
```

Also add meta tag in head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Thanks